# jhipster sample app - how to make sure only owner of resource can delete it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I am currently trying to understand the jhipster sample app at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app

What I dont see how it is prevented that a user deletes a bank account that he doesnt own.
In jhipster-sample-app/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/web/rest/BankAccountResource.java:

```
/**
     * DELETE  /bank-accounts/:id : delete the "id" bankAccount.
     *
     * @param id the id of the bankAccount to delete
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK)
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/bank-accounts/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteBankAccount(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete BankAccount : {}", id);
        bankAccountRepository.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }
```

where bankAccountRepository is a regular Repository.
What if I send an id of a bank account that is not mine? Shouldnt the repository or service make sure that the bank account's user's username is equal to the username from the authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JHipster Sample App shows you what you get right after generating a project and several entities with JHipster.  Because you can't predict what a developer wants in their business logic, JHipster keeps it generalized and uses default configurations when possible (in this case, generic CRUD REST endpoints).

If you wanted to prevent a user from deleting another user's account, you could get their username with [`SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/070c03df773dce566f7610f978669798e0a04c92/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/security/SecurityUtils.java#L22-L34) and validate that it matches the BankAccount's login.

Answer (score 0):

Security wouldn't be configured in there.  It's instead [configured in this class](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/SecurityConfiguration.java) leveraging Spring Security.

From this, you can see that before almost every request, one is required to authenticate with a username and password before they can invoke it.

You'd want to read up a bit more on Spring Security and how that works and integrates with Spring Boot to get the full picture.

Comment: as i understand it, this only makes sure that the user that makes the request is authenticated (by a valid json web token), but it doesnt check if the resource that is requested really belongs to that user

Answer (score 0):

The Jhipster code generated is fairly basic when it comes to rest security.  However, it is explain by IPPON in depth here https://blog.ippon.tech/improving-the-access-control-of-a-jhipster-application/

in your example "Entities owned by a user", which in my humble opinion should be in every deletemapping.   I would also surround with an "admin" check.

```
if (!SecurityUtils.isCurrentUserInRole(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)) {

    Optional<BankAccountDTO> bankAccountDTO = bankAccountRepository.findById(id)
        .map(bankAccountMapper::toDto);

    // Return 404 if the entity is not owned by the connected user
    Optional<String> userLogin = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin();
    if (bankAccountDTO.isPresent() &&
        userLogin.isPresent() &&
        userLogin.get().equals(bankAccountDTO.get().getUserLogin())) {
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(bankAccountDTO);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```